# Checking for negatives in template?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

This isn't a very important problem, but it's something that has been bugging me for a while now. Basically, I've taken up to learning metaprogramming using templates in C++ simply because it seems interesting. In learning I found the simple factorial example:

```
template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = factorial<n - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

From this I wanted to add my own portion taken from an extremely basic program assignment from an introduction course a friend of mine is taking. The only additional part I need to add is to print -1 if the number given is negative.

This is where I'm having trouble. I've tried several different things, but it quickly gets out of hand and the errors are very confusing most of the time. At this point I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this simply. At first I thought it would be as easy as this:

```
template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = (n < 0) ? -1 : factorial<n>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

But this runs in the compiler until it quits when given a negative number. I've also tried several different things involving making 2-6 more functions and temporary typedefs and other things and it becomes a large mess of errors.

So to make this short: Is there a way to conditionally execute another template if the number given is negative? For example, something like this:

```
template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = factorial<n, negative<n>::value>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct factorial<(n < 0)> {
    enum { value = -1 };
};
```

Comment: You don't "execute" templates, they are not executable code.

Comment: @Jonathan: It is not unreasonable to think of them as the *compiler* executing your templates to generate the functions that will be put in an executable.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I think it is unhelpful, because it can give the misleading impression that the same kind of imperative programming style can be used with templates as with "normal" C++ code. Template metaprogramming requires a very different approach, and it is better to avoid any confusion related to "executing" or "running" anything. For example, both branches of the `?:` operator in the OP's question get "executed" because the compiler instantiates the templates in both branches.

Comment: @Jonathan: I see how it can be unhelpful if you fail to distinguish between the compiler executing the metaprogram to produce components of your program, and the CPU executing the binary created by the linker. But learning that distinction is *really* helpful. Incidentally, a declarative style does work okay for metaprogramming once you adjust to the quirk that all variables are constant. Of course it's more common to think of metaprogramming in a functional style.

Comment: Use `unsigned` instead of `int` and this is no longer a problem.

Comment: @Radiodef That is still a problem. First it is against the initial design. Second, if you pass in -1 you'd get an extremely large number and since the base case is 0 the compiler would stop way before it reached that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, like this:

```
namespace detail {
    template <int n, bool isNegative>
    struct factorial_impl {
        enum { value = n * factorial_impl<n - 1, isNegative>::value };
    };

    template <int n>
    struct factorial_impl<n, true> {
        enum { value = -1 };
    };

    template <>
    struct factorial_impl<0, false> {
        enum { value = 1 };
    };
}

template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = detail::factorial_impl<n, n < 0>::value };
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ba56b7f188a3ab)

Comment: That was pretty fast! I could swear I tried something similar to this before though. I'll have to compare it to some of my previous iterations. Thanks for the answer!